# Double faced cards multiple transform triggers

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-double-faced-cards

Wizards recently [changed the ruling](http://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/archive/feature/shadows-over-innistrad-mechanics) for double faced cards:

> if a DFC has an activated or triggered ability that transforms it, that permanent transforms only if it hasn't since that ability was put on the stack.

Ok, so that means that you can't flip-flop a DFC card around with the ability on one side. Does that mean you can't activate/trigger the ability more than once, for other effects? (e.g. Elusive Tormentor's "{1}, Discard a card: Transform" and I want multiple Madness triggers)

Comment: Your second question: Do you mean it's not on the stack ever? Or it's not on the stack when a non-Angel creature dies?

Comment: I think by now the 2nd question is better off as its own question since it is more about the timing of delayed triggered abilities rather than the DFC rules changes.

Comment: @Hackworth bah, i was worried that its scope would get too big. Will do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several points for the first question:

- Elusive Tormentor's ability is not triggered, it is activated.
- Discarding the card is not part of its effect, but part of the cost, and there is no limit to how often you activate that ability.
- Even if it was part of the effect, you could still activate the ability several times and discard several cards, because the discard and the flip would be separate effects. If one effect of a spell or ability gets prevented or replaced somehow, the other effects are not affected.

Comment: @murgatroid99 Not sure any more, I assumed he meant when a non-angel creature dies. I asked him to clarify.